# Do the default settings of NetworkManager detect if there is a conflicting IPv4 address on the network?

Tags: networkmanager, ipv4

> - Added support for detecting duplicate IPv4 addresses, with a timeout
>     configurable through the ipv4.dad-timeout connection property.
>
> -- [NEWS](https://github.com/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/blob/master/NEWS)

---

> dad-timeout / int32 / -1
>
> Timeout in milliseconds used to check for the presence of duplicate IP addresses on the network. If an address conflict is detected, the activation will fail. A zero value means that no duplicate address detection is performed, -1 means the default value (either configuration `ipvx.dad-timeout` override or zero). A value greater than zero is a timeout in milliseconds. The property is currently implemented only for IPv4.
>
> -- [IPv4 Settings](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/settings-ipv4.html)
>
> Quote taken from the manual for NetworkManager, as of version 1.14.4.

I failed to find `ipvx.dad-timeout` documented anywhere.  It is described as an "override", not a default.  So it sounds more likely that `ipvx.dad-timeout` is not set by default.  In other words, the default is not to enable IPv4 Duplicate Address Detection.  Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These properties are generally part of the connection profile. However, some of these properties have a special value that indicates the "default" value. For those, the default value may be configured in NetworkManager.conf. Consequently, that's documented in `man NetworkManager.conf` -- as opposed to `man nm-settings`.

But note that the default value in NetworkManager.conf only matters if you don't specify an explicit value in the profile itself. The profile's value has precedence.

"-1 means the default value (either configuration ipvx.dad-timeout override or zero)" means that -1 is the default value for this property in the profile. This allows fallback to a configured default value in NetworkManager.conf, and in case that it is still unspecified there, the final value 0 (disabled) is used.

Comment: Ahh.  I see there is not a literal setting `ipvx.dad-timeout`, but there is a global setting `ipv4.dad-timeout` corresponding to the connection setting `ipv4.dad-timeout`.  (And the same for ipv6, except the setting is not implemented for ipv6 yet anyway, which is why it is not mentioned in the current version of `man NetworkManager.conf`).

Answer (score 0):

By default the parameter is set to `-1` , you can check it through :

```
nmcli con show "connexion_name" | grep ipv4.dad-timeout
```

Use the `nmcli con show` to get the name of the connexion.